# Fix duplicate entries in VBA dictionary

Tags: vba, dictionary

I am trying to fix duplicate entries in a dictionary and roll them up into one entry. For example, I have the following dictionary entries.

[image: > Blockquote]

As you can see, May-1 has two entries and two separate values. How do I roll them up into one entry and show as below:
[image]

This is what I am struggling with:

```
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

Dim i As Long
Dim ColumnAKey As Variant
Dim ColumnBValue As Variant
Dim ColumnBValues As Collection

For i = 1 To 6
    ColumnAKey = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value
    ColumnBValue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value
    If Not dict.Exists(ColumnAKey) Then
        dict.Add ColumnAKey, New Collection
        Set ColumnBValues = dict.Item(ColumnDKey)
        ColumnBValues.Add ColumnBValue
    Else
        Set ColumnBValues = dict.Item(ColumnAKey)
        ColumnBValues.Add dict.Item(ColumnAKey)(1) + ColumnBValue
    End If
Next i

For Each ColumnAKey In dict.Keys
    Set ColumnBValues = dict.Item(ColumnAKey)
    
    For Each ColumnBValue In ColumnBValues
        Debug.Print ColumnAKey & " - " & ColumnBValue
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Please explain what are duplicate entries in this case since a dictionary can't have duplicate keys. Also, explain how the collections fit into the story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one entry per key, then you don't need a collection for each key.

I assume, you want something like this:

```vb
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim i As Long
Dim ColumnAKey As Variant
Dim ColumnBValue As Variant

For i = 1 To 6
    ColumnAKey = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value
    ColumnBValue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value
    If Not dict.Exists(ColumnAKey) Then
        dict.Add ColumnAKey, ColumnBValue 
    Else
        dict.Item(ColumnAKey) = dict.Item(ColumnAKey) + ColumnBValue
    End If
Next i

For Each ColumnAKey In dict.Keys
    Debug.Print ColumnAKey & " - " & dict.Item(ColumnAKey)
Next
```

Comment: I think it should be `Debug.Print ColumnAKey & " - " & dict(ColumnAKey)`.

Comment: Also, instead of the If statement, you can use this: `dict(ColumnAKey) = dict(ColumnAKey) + ColumnBValue`.

Comment: @Domenic, thanks, you are of course right, I fixed it in the answer.

Comment: @VBasic2008, you are also right, I was aware of this but wanted to change the original code as little as possible to make it more clear what was going on.